# How to redirect a URL with parameters?

Tags: plugins, errors, redirect

My redirection are working until parameters are added to the end of the source URL. What will be the proper way of implementing a redirect were the target will be a different URL but I want to pass the parameters untouched.

[Post with Parameters goes to 404 page](http://www.kiragiannis.com/2009/03/windows-restarts-at-ec2.html?action=backlinks&widgetId=Blog1&widgetType=Blog&responseType=js&postID=5852350893114831887)

[Same post without parameters redirects properly](http://www.kiragiannis.com/cloud-computing/windows-restarts-at-ec2/)

I am using the following pluging for the redirects:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem ain't the parameters...it's that your parametrized URL points to the wrong target...it has a `.html` where it should have a slash.

```
.../windows-restarts-at-ec2.html?action=backlinks&wid...
```

Change it to

```
..../windows-restarts-at-ec2/?action=backlinks&wid...
```

and you'll see it works.

Comment: I see that it works.  The issue that I have is that the links with the html at the end are real link linking back in the internet to my site.  Because those sites are using parameters and the .html at the end, my page is returning a 404. any advice for this?

Comment: @Geo Well, whoever has those links on their sites is either doing something wrong themselves or getting the wrong links from you.

Comment: I had the blog at blogger before and there they worked.  I did not do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

change `".html?action"` to `"/?action".`
It worked in blogger because pages in blogger ends in "`.html`"